# how to navigate to settings in android emulator using robotium?

Tags: robotium

I am a newbie for Robotium and till then I managed to learn a lot by directly writing test cases for public websites and sorted out several issues from answers in stackoverflow. now, I seemed to hit the wall at this (probably)trivial problem.

I would like to navigate to 'Settings' icon which is inside 'Apps' menu of the android emulator using some sort of 'robotium-solo' method.

This is my failed attempt:

```
solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
//solo.clickOnImageButton(2); // no success!
//solo.clickOnActionBarItem(2); // no success!
solo.clickOnText("Settings");
solo.clickOnText("Music");
```

I checked for any KEYCODE_var for home screen 'app' icon but couldn't find one.

There is no useful log message in DDMS to figure out the starting activity when clicked/tapped on that button.s

Please guide me whether my approach is any good and help me with an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the app or u r automating with `apk` file??

Comment: Hi Keerthana, YES, I am automating with an apk alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can check with `getCurrentViews()` and have the list of `view`s displayed before clicking the menu button and after clicking the menu button.By comparing them you can get the view of the new views displayed (i.e. settings button).

After getting the view,you can go with `solo.clickOnView(ViewNameObtained);` 
This will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: here is my code: `public void testClearAppData() { solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME); 
//solo.clickOnImageButton(2); 
//solo.clickOnActionBarItem(2); 
//solo.clickOnView(); 
ArrayList <View> views = solo.getCurrentViews(); 
for (View i : views){ 
System.out.println(i.toString()); 
} 
}`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, navigating to settings is not possible with robotium. Even if you would be able to go there you cannot perform any other action as Settings are not port of your application. Android Instrumentation allows performing actions only within one package and robotium is only wrapper for that, so it's not able to click outside your application as well.

You can use UI Automator for that.

Comment: UIAutomator looks promising on its own which means I cannot combine/use them in my robotium test cases. It seems, If I want to use this UIAutomator capabilities in my robotium test cases, it seems difficult because I cannot inherit both `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and `UIAutomatorTestCase` to create my own testcase class. Any further guidance could be helpful.